# Best practices for web application in AWS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm currently beginning development on a web application for school that will act as a lesson plan database of sorts for educators to search for, upload, and download files for a lesson plan. I have my EC2 instance setup for building my PHP application and my RDS deployed for my MySQL.

I'm slowly learning PHP for the things I need to incorporate on our client's webpage, but as I do more research, I see other methods such as using Elastic-Beanstalk, host with S3 storage, Dynamo...I thought I knew generally where to start, but I guess I'm a bit lost as to how to go about this without making mine and the client's head spin.

Our application wants to somewhat mirror this setup, but I don't think we'll be using a flash application: http://spirit.unomaha.edu/

Are there any recommendations on how to approach this?
More specifically, how do I make PHP talk to the EC2 and allow file uploads in that bucket? That is, I want the file stored on AWS not a temp folder.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What are you running on the EC2 that PHP needs to talk to? And where are you running yoru PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Amazon AWS EC2 Storage Options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890511/amazon-aws-ec2-storage-options)

Comment: I want the PHP to be able to upload files to the EC2 storage. If I enable uploads in the html, I don't think it will act the same way. As of now, I'm trying to figure out how to setup phpmyadmin on the ec2. I found a thread here listing some steps for that: http://superuser.com/questions/291230/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-linux-ec2-instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are talking about uploading a file to S3, not to a bucket in EC2.

Here is the documentation for the PHP SDK (and specifically the part you would use to upload files to S3):
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html

As for your setup, the easiest way to go would be to run your application on Elastic Beanstalk, use RDS for database, and S3 for storage.

But running the application on an EC2 instance, with RDS for database and S3 for storage, will work just as well, but it requires a little more work on your part if you want to take advantage of the auto-scaling features of AWS.

This is basically how you would upload a file to S3 from your application:

```
    $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
        'key' => 'YOUR_KEY',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET'
    ));
    $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => 'MyBucket',
        'Key' => 'myFolder/myFile.txt',
        'SourceFile' => '/path/to/temp/upload/file',
        'ACL' => 'private' // Access config
    ));
```

Comment: Ah, I figured EC2 would be a bit overkill for a simple search/upload/download app like this. I'll explore the S3 route again with Elastic Beanstalk. Thanks so much!